# How to print function on if statement?

Tags: python

How do I print the function 'play' in the if statement on line 5?

```
print("Deal 'Em\nby Imago Games")
print("1. Play\n2. Credits")
select = input()
if select == 1:
    def play()
elif select == 1:
    print("Bye")
def play():
    print("Welcome to Deal 'Em\nLet me teach you the basics!")
```

Comment: Is it print(play)? Or print(def(play))?

Comment: This code is syntactically incorrect and based on how you are structuring this code, I think there are certain fundamentals that you need to revise.

Comment: I am a newbie. I am just learning functions. I will certainly revise, i have a long weekend.

Answer (score 3):

There are three major problems in your code:

- `play()` is defined before usage. You have to define the function earlier in your code.
- to call the function use `play()` without `def`
- your `elif` has the same condition as the `if` and will never be executed

Comment: Thank you. I should've known to define the function first. I also didn't know you can write it without def to print it.

Comment: Oops I meant to write 2 for elif, not 1. I was in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

You can put either just `play()` on line 5 (remove the `def`) or change the `play` function to return the string instead of printing it. `def` is only used when you define the function, not when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it as play(), the print is already inside the function

Comment: It can be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `def play()` on line 5, use `play()` to simply call the function. Also, you should work on the structure of your code and place all the function definitions before calling them.